# Comparison Function as Parameter in Racket

Tags: function, sorting, racket, programming-languages

I've implemented selection sort as follows in Racket:

```
#lang racket
(define (selection-sort lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) '()]
        [else (define first (apply min lst))
              (cons first (selection-sort(remove first lst)))]))

(selection-sort (list 5 4 3))
```

However I'm asked that my function take in a comparison function along with my list, and selection sort should return a list in ascending order according to the comparison function.

I'm having trouble understanding this bit with the comparison function, what do I need to change about the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear in mind that the current implementation is quite inefficient, you're doing a lot of extra looping in there: when finding the minimum, when removing it.

Having said that, we can adapt the code to receive a comparison function by writing our own `min` that receives an arbitrary comparison function - because implicitly, `min` was using `<`. Like this:

```
(define (selection-sort lst cmp)
  (cond [(empty? lst) '()]
        [else (define amin (mymin cmp lst))
              (cons amin (selection-sort (remove amin lst) cmp))]))

(define (mymin cmp lst)
  ; assuming non-empty list
  (cond [(empty? (rest lst))
         (first lst)]
        ; call the recursion
        [else (define amin (mymin cmp (rest lst)))
              ; use the comparison function
              (cond [(cmp (first lst) amin) (first lst)]
                    [else amin])]))
```

It works as expected:

```
; ascending order, this was the default behavior
(selection-sort (list 5 4 3) <)
=> '(3 4 5)
; same as above
(selection-sort (list 5 4 3) (lambda (x y) (< x y)))
=> '(3 4 5)
; descending order
(selection-sort (list 5 4 3) >)
=> '(5 4 3)
```